# Setting column sizes in kivy GridLayout not working

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to make a screen with a little header and then some rows where the user can input information. For now I'm just working with one row with two buttons so that I can clearly see their sizes. I'm forcing the row height to be 50dp, and would like the first column to have this same width as it will just contain some icons (any help on centering these icons within the cell would also be appreciated... perhaps wrap it in another AnchorLayout?), the second column should just take up the rest of the screen. I have tried setting the size_hint on the GridLayout to None, None, size_hint_x to None, setting size and position hints on the buttons, setting them to None. There are different results sometimes but none of them actually do what I want. I also came across something that said to specify the minimum widths of the columns, but as I would like the code to be dynamic and adjust automatically rather than hardcoding pixels. I guess something is blocking the size parameters I'm setting, but I have no idea where. I have also tried with and without row_force_default as I read it ignores size_hints. Here's my current code:

new_tour.kv

```
#:import images_path kivymd.images_path
#:import utils kivy.utils

<NewTourScreen@MDScreen>:
    MDFloatLayout:
        MDGridLayout:
            # Top bar with exit button and create trip text
            rows: 1
            size_hint: 1, 0.075
            pos_hint: {"top": 1, "left": 1}
            
            canvas:
                Color: 
                    rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#2e6407")
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            
            MDIconButton:
                size_hint: 0.15, 1
                pos_hint: {"top": 1, "right": 1}

                icon: "window-close"
                on_release: root.manager.current = "my_tours"
                theme_icon_color: "Custom"
                icon_color: "white"
                
            MDLabel:
                size_hint: 0.85, 1
                text: "Create a new trip"
                bold: True
                font: "Proxima Nova"
                color: "white"

        MDGridLayout:
            # Grid containing input fields
            id: new_tour_grid

            cols: 2
            size_hint_x: 1
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.925}

            row_default_height: dp(50)
            row_force_default: True

            # Row 1: tour name
            Button:
                size_x: dp(50)
                on_release: print(self.size)

            Button:
                id: new_tour_name
                on_release: print(self.size)
```

main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from tour_grid import TourGrid
from new_tour import NewTourGrid
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivymd.uix.pickers import MDDatePicker
import requests
import json


class Main(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        # self.theme_cls.material_style = "M3"
        # self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        Window.size = (360, 600)
        print(Window.size)
        return Builder.load_file("main.kv")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    LabelBase.register(name="Proxima Nova", fn_regular="fonts/Proxima Nova/proximanova_regular.ttf", fn_bold="fonts/Proxima Nova/proximanova_bold.otf")
    Main().run()
```

main.kv

```
#:include kv/new_tour.kv

BoxLayout:
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager

        NewTourScreen:
            id: new_tour
            name: "new_tour"
```

I tried to remove pieces of code unnecessary to the question as much as possible, hope that runs okay. Thanks for any suggestions!

EDIT:
When using the Buttons, it seems that simply adding `size_hint_x: 0.15` to the first Button does the job. However, when I then change the widgets to an MDIcon and MDTextField it does not keep these settings. I don't understand what the size priorities are here...